# Is there a way to set Blender to start rendering an animation at a specific hour?

Tags: python, rendering, animation

I am rendering a massive animation by doing a short segment every night. However, my computer is very loud when rendering and it disturbs others working in my office. Is there a way, with python maybe, to leave Blender open with the scene and have it automatically start rendering the set frame range at a time in the evening when I know everyone has left the office, say 8 p.m?

I have asked whoever leaves last to start it but they always forget :/

Comment: If you're using windows you could use a batch file and set a scheduled task to run said .bat file I suppose.

Comment: And if you're on some *nix flavour, you can use a shell script started from a cron job. Take a look at https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/render/workflows/command_line.html for information on how to start Blender from a command line.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I often use batch files with maya/vray, but I have never got it to work with blender. I can open my .blend from the cmd/batch file but if I add a command like -a to render animation it never recognizes them and just wont open.